# What does "nodetool compact" do for DateTieredCompactionStrategy?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax, nodetool

[The documentation for nodetool compact says](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsCompact.html):

> This command starts the compaction process on tables that use the
>   SizeTieredCompactionStrategy and DateTieredCompactionStrategy. You can
>   specify a keyspace for compaction.

But what it does for DateTieredCompactionStrategy?

Side question: what is `-s, --split-output` parameter? It is explained as: `Use -s to not create a single big file`. I'm confused - isn't that the purpose of `nodetool compact`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nodetool compact with no flags will still create a big single file even with DTCS.

The -s, --split-output option is only there starting with c* 2.2 and beyond.

The news.txt states:

```
 +     It is also possible to split output when doing a major compaction with
 +     STCS - files will be split in sizes 50%, 25%, 12.5% etc of the total size.
 +     This might be a bit better than old major compactions which created one big
 +     file on disk.
```

On DTCS -s won't do anything special (will still create one large sstable)

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! Side question: any clue what can I do when for one or two days the compaction was broken (until the node restart) and during that time the node created 2000 SSTables without compacting them?

Comment: How was it broken? Did you turn off autocompaction?

Comment: I'm not sure, but there are two options: 1. nodetool repair failed and it didn't clear/compact created 2000 sstables, OR 2. after nodetool repair failed, a bug stopped autocompaction until restart.

Comment: More likely your repair just generated lots of sstables. Autocompaction is still running but is a bit behind. Are you running vnodes?

Comment: Yes, that's also possible. The problem is that the age of generated sstables passed max_sstable_age_days. Therefore, those many sstables won't be automatically compacted. Yes, I'm using vnodes.

Comment: This is actually a known limitation of older versions of DTCS, due to max_sstable_age_days. I discussed it in detail at Cassandra Summit 2015 ( http://www.slideshare.net/JeffJirsa1/cassandra-summit-2015-real-world-dtcs-for-operators ) - you'll need to either increase max_sstable_age_days OR manually join the tiny sstables (which came from repair) using forceUserDefinedCompaction. Or you could try https://github.com/jeffjirsa/twcs , which I wrote to address this limitation.